# ServiceStack web service hosting on monotouch/monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, servicestack, xamarin

I'm currently trying to host a REST webservice on ios/android using Xamarin and monotouch/monodroid. I already successfully have a basic webserver running using HttpListener, but now I would like to host a complete webservice using ServiceStack.

monotouch/monodroid have very limited web hosting capabilities (HttpListener is basically the only way), but ServiceStack can *in theory* accomodate with that.

It seems to be possible as I found someone who did it: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=417

The problem is that project does not work anymore on the last monotouch version, and ServiceStack seems to have removed server hosting capabilites in the monotouch/monodroid latest builds...

Xamarin have a fork of ServiceStack (https://github.com/xamarin/ServiceStack) which seems to have hosting capabilities, but the monotouch specific service hosting build does not compile, and the fork seems outdated.

Has anyone succeeded in making the ServiceStack hosting capabilities work on monotouch/monodroid? Or do you have an idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after some research, the project to allow ServiceStack self-hosting has been dropped. It had a better luck with the (old) Xamarin version (https://github.com/xamarin/ServiceStack) and could compile it and make it work somehow.

Since I need to be in sync with the latest ServiceStack version, I guess that I have no other choice than to roll my own adaptation, using the old Xamarin branch as a starting point.

Comment: did you manage to do anything with hosting ServiceStack in an Xamarin app ? The old Xamarin fork on GitHub does not support hosting it's only for client

Answer (score 3):

You might try [this tutorial](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting) for self-hosting ServiceStack.

It looks like it will use `HttpListener` under the hood, but I don't know if the `AppHostHttpListenerBase` class will compile for MonoTouch/Mono for Android or not.

Comment: This exactly what I am trying to achieve, the problem is to compile a monotouch/droid compatible dll that includes `AppHostHttpListenerBase`. ServiceStack used to have it in older versions (like in my link) but not anymore, the Xamarin fork also have it but neither compile on the latest monotouch version.

Comment: It looks like they just have "Project Options->Compiler->Treat warnings as errors" checked in all their projects. I unchecked these, then only compiled ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Common, and ServiceStack.Interfaces and it seemed to build just fine. Is this class in one of these three projects?

Comment: I bet you're talking of the Xamarin version? I did the same thing, and the compiler crashes on ServiceStack.Interfaces compilation. Anyway, the interesting classes are in ServiceStack.dll which compile just fine, but it is not a monotouch project (and then does not work on monotouch, even using the monotouch target).

The replacement for this dll is located under ServiceStack.MonoTouch, which does not build due to a lot of errors :(

Comment: Mine was building under the MonoTouch target, but I'll try the ServiceStack.MonoTouch.sln -- I didn't see it